# How did my answer end up being Community Wiki?

Tags: support

So:

[Pizza in Oven : Bottom/Mid/Top](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24020/pizza-in-oven-bottom-mid-top)

Somehow my answer is now marked "community wiki".  I'm not sure how this happened; I'm concerned that I accidentally hit a check box or something which caused it to become community wiki, which I certainly didn't intend.  It doesn't seem canonical enough to be wiki to me.

If a moderator make it community wiki, it would be nice to have some kind of indication that this was so.  If I did it accidentally, it would be nice to be able to undo it.

Answer (score 2):

The history says that you made it community wiki yourself. Probably you checked the checkbox without noticing. I reverted it for you.

"Community wiki" doesn't mean that you think that your answer is good enough to serve as a canonical answer or similar. It is intended for cases where you have half the answer and hope that other people will supply the missing half. Marking it "community wiki" means that you don't get any reputation from upvotes, because the answer is going to be a collaborative effort.

An answer can also automatically get to be "community wiki" when it has had a large number of edits by different people. I forgot how high this number is, but it doesn't usually happen on our site.